# DRF other fields in serializer on get and on post

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying for a few hour how to get other fields representation in serializer when i'm doing get and other when i'm doing post.
[image]

I want this all data which are in author field in json, but lower in html form i want only choose exist user from list. When i change author field to display only url then i can choose author from list.
[image]

Is it possible to get author info like on first screen and have only possibility to choose author from user list without editing all user fields?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is **author** as a ForeignKey in You Model.

Something like:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(
    Author,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
```